vscode rust devcontainer: cargo build resulting in "failed to link or copy"
i am running in vscode rust devcontainer (based on mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/rust:1-1-bullseye)
i have the following structure (Note: the target and Cargo.lock do not exist until after i attempt a cargo build:

My toml looks like this:
[package]
name = "aipg_client"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
tokio-postgres = "0.7.10"

when i do Cargo build or run from command line, i see this:
vscode ➜ /workspaces/aipg_client $ cargo build
   Compiling libc v0.2.154
   Compiling typenum v1.17.0
   Compiling proc-macro2 v1.0.82
   Compiling generic-array v0.14.7
   Compiling lock_api v0.4.12
   Compiling slab v0.4.9
   Compiling parking_lot_core v0.9.10
error: failed to link or copy `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/parking_lot_core-cee070a7360e29f1/build_script_build-cee070a7360e29f1` to `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/parking_lot_core-cee070a7360e29f1/build-script-build`

Caused by:
  Operation not permitted (os error 1)
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
error: failed to link or copy `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-b4c719e575383218/build_script_build-b4c719e575383218` to `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/proc-macro2-b4c719e575383218/build-script-build`

Caused by:
  Operation not permitted (os error 1)
error: failed to link or copy `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/libc-a5f595ef1ee1b008/build_script_build-a5f595ef1ee1b008` to `/workspaces/aipg_client/target/debug/build/libc-a5f595ef1ee1b008/build-script-build`

i checked these folders and they are all r/w.
What am i doing wrong?
EDIT 1: devcontainer, docker files
devcontainer.json
{
    "name": "aipg_client",
    // Or use a Dockerfile or Docker Compose file. More info: https://containers.dev/guide/dockerfile
    "dockerComposeFile": ["docker-compose.yml"],    
    "service": "aipg_client",
    "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces/${localWorkspaceFolderBasename}",
    // "workspaceFolder": "/workspaces",
    // "mounts": ["source=target,target=/workspaces/aipg_client/target,type=volume"],
    // "postCreateCommand": "sudo chown vscode:vscode /workspaces/aipg_client/arget"

}

dokcer-compose.yml:
networks:
  aipg_client_net:
    driver: bridge

services:
  aipg_client:
    container_name: aipg_client_${ENV}
    image: "aipg_client:${VERSION}"
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
      target: aipg_client_local
      args:
        ENV: ${ENV:-local}
        USER_ID: ${USER_ID:-1000}
        GROUP_ID: ${GROUP_ID:-1000}
        USER_NAME: ${USER_NAME}
      shm_size: '2gb'
    env_file:
      - ./.env
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces
      - ~/.ssh:/home/${USER_NAME}/.ssh
      - //var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    command: sleep infinity
    shm_size: 0.94gb
    ports: 
      - "${SVC_PORT}:5000"    
    networks:
      - aipg_client_net

dockerfile:
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/devcontainers/rust:1-1-bullseye as aipg_client_base
ENV TZ=America/New_York

ARG ENV
ARG USER_ID
ARG GROUP_ID
ARG USER_NAME

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install acl iputils-ping less libpq-dev nano postgresql-client sudo

RUN groupadd -g $GROUP_ID -o $USER_NAME
RUN useradd -m -s /bin/bash -u $USER_ID -g $GROUP_ID $USER_NAME

FROM aipg_client_base as aipg_client_local

RUN mkdir -p /workspaces/aipg_client/target
RUN chown -R vscode:vscode /workspaces/aipg_client/target
RUN chmod -R 777 /workspaces/aipg_client/target

#USER $USER_ID

What's interesting is if move target outside the workspace by adding a .cargo/config.toml, it works fine.  but ofcourse this isnt a good solution this any path outside the workspace remains ephemeral.

Can you share your devcontainer.json file?
